# Regex to find words/number after a particular word

Tags: regex

My String: {“ID”:”NOKIA-71E1”,”KY”:”59ad728d99”,”U”:”admin”,”P”:”cfa522ec5a”,”S”:”FSH21290288A”,”23S”:”DC8D8A4171E1”,”N”:”5G12-13W-A”,”PN”:”3TG00799ABAA”,”IMEI”:”352778340662308”}

I need to get two outputs from the above string.

1. The string after "s": which is FSH21290288A
2. The string after "IMEI": which is 352778340662308

Comment: What have you tried? Also, do you mean JSON?

Comment: What OS/RDBMS/program or editor are you doing this in?  Not all regex's are created equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that quotes, In your question quotes and regex are same

Solution:

```
"S":"(?<S>.*?)".*"IMEI":"(?<IMEI>.*?)".*
```

Regex Link: [enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/M8HJgd/1)

Just FYI:

```
{“ID”:”NOKIA-71E1”,”KY”:”59ad728d99”,”U”:”admin”,”P”:”cfa522ec5a”,”S”:”FSH21290288A”,”23S”:”DC8D8A4171E1”,”N”:”5G12-13W-A”,”PN”:”3TG00799ABAA”,”IMEI”:”352778340662308”}
```

” - This quates in regex is diierent than the regex

" - This quates is in regex
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[“”"]S[“”"]:[“”"])[^“”"]*(?=[“”"])
(?<=[“”"]IMEI[“”"]:[“”"])[^“”"]*(?=[“”"])
```

These experessions use lookahead and lookbehind groups, you can read more about them in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/552563).

Comment: It's showing the correct output when I copied the input string and then copied the regex code you provided in https://regex101.com/. But not working with my VB code. I am using this pattern with VB

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what tools you are using here to be more specific, this regex will return the strings you need in the capture groups \1 and \2.  [See regex101 example here.](https://regex101.com/r/DGqsq7/1)

```
"S":"(.*?)".*"IMEI":"(.*?)".*
```

Comment: It's showing the correct output when I clicked the link you mentioned. But when I copied the input string and then copied the regex code you provided it's not giving any output.

I am using this pattern with VB